# Python Code exceeds maximum recursion depth

Tags: python, class, recursion

I am new to python and I am doing testing.

when I run following code, the error message "RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded"

```
names = ['G','K']

class test(object):

    def __init__(self, names):
        self.players = []
        for name in names:
            player = test(name)
            self.players.append(player)
        print(self.players)

G = test(names)
```

Can anyone tell me what went wrong and how to solve it?
Thank you very much!!!

Comment: How is SQL involved in this question?

Comment: What do you expect? You create instances of `test` inside `test.__init__`.

Comment: What are you trying to do? Please explain your goals in words.

Comment: Every time you do `test()`, it will call `test.__init__()`. Since `test.__init__()` also calls `test()`, you get an infinite recursion.

Comment: when create an instance, the class will automatically print out self.player = ['G','K'].

Comment: Your code doesn't make any sense. Can you please describe what you are trying to accomplish? What purpose does `test` serve? Why are you instantiating another `test` object in the `test.__init__`? I.e. why `player = test(name)`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As others have pointed out, every time you create a new instance of `test`, `player = test(name)`, you are calling test, thus enabling infinite recursion. Instead, just create a list of a different class instance for each name, presumably a `collections.namedtuple`:

```
import collections
class test(object):
   def __init__(self, names):
      player = collections.namedtuple('player', 'name')
      self.players = list(map(player._make, names))

names = ['G','K']
G = test(names)
for player in G.players:
   print(player.name)
```

Answer (score 0):

Every time you call test, you then call test again, inside itself.

This goes on until the computer has no more space to hold the theoretically infinite versions of test you have asked it to.

Comment: That depends rather a lot on what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you @Ajax1234, your way works.

I was learning from Michael Dawson's python for beginner and was trying to learn from his codes.

Actually all I need to do is just to use `player = name` rather than `player = test(name)`

Thank you all for your speedy anserws